# async await progressbar with MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, asynchronous, mvvm

how can I achieve progressbar or progress status with MVVM. Basically below is how my ViewModel looks like.
I basically I fire the getdata function by implementing Relaycommand in the inherited CrudVMBase class. when It finishes it is job, it will raise property changed for ProductModels and this is binded to datagrid in my xaml as shown below. This takes sometimes up to an hour. I would like to implement some status/progress information to the xaml. Not sure if I can achieve this using

Messenger.[Default].Send(Of UserMessage)(msg)

funcztion of MvvmLight. I am using it already returning the exceptions as shown in the try catch part below.

```
Namespace ViewModels


    Public Class CheckProductsViewModel
        Inherits CrudVMBase


        Private m_ProductModels As ObservableCollection(Of ProductVM)
        Public Property ProductModels() As ObservableCollection(Of ProductVM)
            Get
                Return m_ProductModels
            End Get
            Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ProductVM))
                m_ProductModels = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub

        Private _totalTime As String
        Public Property totalTime() As String
            Get
                Return _totalTime
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _totalTime = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Protected Overrides Async Sub GetData()
            Dim watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
            ThrobberVisible = Visibility.Visible
            Try

               Dim myProducts = Await (myContext.Products.Where(Function(w) w.Name <> "").ToListAsync())

                Dim myProductComponent As New ProductComponent
               Dim _ProductModels As ObservableCollection(Of ProductVM)

                Dim counter = 0

                Dim tasks = myProducts.Select(Function(x) myProductComponent.testUrl_async(x))
                Dim results = Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

              Dim r = (From item In results Where item IsNot Nothing Select New ProductVM With { _
                   .IsNew = False, _
                   .TheProductModel = item _
               }).ToList()

                _ProductModels = New ObservableCollection(Of ProductVM)(r)
                ProductModels = _ProductModels
                watch.Stop()
                totalTime = "total time:" & Math.Round(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString

                RaisePropertyChanged("totalTime")
                RaisePropertyChanged("ProductModels")
            Catch ex As Exception
              Dim msg As New UserMessage()
            msg.isException = True
            msg.Message = ex.ToString
            Messenger.[Default].Send(Of UserMessage)(msg)
            End Try

            ThrobberVisible = Visibility.Collapsed
        End Sub

    End Class


End Namespace
```

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
            <cst:CustomDataGrid x:Name="grdProduct"                                                             
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductModels, IsAsync=True}"                
                 Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"    
                 Style="{StaticResource myDataGrid2}"
                  >
    ....              
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a "Progress" property to your CheckProductsViewModel ?
Make it implement RaisePropertyChanged event, and in your xaml bind that value to the ProgressBar's value property.

Unless I'm not understanding the question clearly, there is absolutely no need to the the MVVMLight's Messenger here